# Suddenly got error message Maps API deactivation and Maps API exceeded quota but everything is normal in the API console

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I suddenly got some random message saying "Google has deactivate Maps API" and "Site has exceed daily quota". Image attached (in Indonesian language).

In the console API the quota status is still green. This started three days ago. What would cause this?

I am using Google Maps API for Javascript version 3.17.

[image: Map deactivation]
[image: Daily quota exceed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It looks like it's a bug with Google**: [Intermittent Google maps api Authorization Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479634/intermittent-google-maps-api-authorization-error?rq=1)
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7464

Other possible answers:

I'm seeing other people with the same problem. It looks like Google gives that error message even then the actual problem is something else.

You can get this error if you don't actually enable the version of Google Maps that you're using: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/2/13/Getting-a-quote-error-with-Google-and-youve-barely-touched-your-limit

You may have already checked that since you've been in the console to check your usage but including it just in case.

Not having referrers set up properly will also cause it:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/google-has-disabled-use-of-maps-api-for-this-application

[Google maps api v3 reporting key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574943/google-maps-api-v3-reporting-key-error?rq=1)

People have also found that taking the key out for a while seems to help (though it is unclear why): [Different errors (quota, disabled, bad API key, or none) when loading Google Maps API JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993927/different-errors-quota-disabled-bad-api-key-or-none-when-loading-google-map)
(Scroll to the bottom of the page for the answer)

Answer (score 2):

I also started getting these errors unexpectedly, even though I was a long way from my quota.
I think maybe the browser was making too many requests for the API key for each load, or something.

So, I changed the "requests per user" setting from 1 to 2 per second, and the errors went away.

Comment: I also did this do. The errors went away. But I don't know whether it was because of this or the issues got fixed by Google at the same time.